# database design for category and sub-category and brand list

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures

I am having a table with categories

```
category
  Electronics
subcategory for electronics
  Mobile
  TV..etc
Mobile brand list
  Nokia
  Samsung..etc
```

At present i have two table one for category and other for sub-category and mobile brand. I am confused in designing between sub-category and brand list. How can i do it. Any suggestions

Comment: I'd suggest posting your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having
`Category` Table, `Subcategory` Table, `Brand` Table and `Subcategory_Brand` may serve:

```
Category:
  Electronics
Subcategory (of Electronics):                Brand:
   Mobile                                      Nokia
   TV                                          Sumsung 
Subcategory_Brand(of Mobile)                    
  Nokia
  Samsung
```